# Color table cell depending on cell data

Tags: java, javafx

I found a good example on the Internet how to do this, in fact it does not work. Below is the code with my comments, please help to figure out what's what and why it doesn't work.

```
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
timeContractColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
            return new TableCell<MainData, LocalDate>() { // MainData - model,
// where all variables and collections for storing data are stored
// timeContractColumn - stores the entered date, therefore, LocalDate
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) { //If the cell is empty
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    } else { //If the cell is not empty

                        setText(item.toString()); //We place the data in the cell
                        System.out.println(item);

                        // We get here all the information about this line.
                        MainData auxPerson = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                        System.out.println(auxPerson.toString());

                        // Change the style if ...
                        if (auxPerson.getTimeContract().equals("2019-04-09")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                        } else {
                            //Here we see whether the row of this cell is highlighted or not
                            if(getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().contains(auxPerson))
                                setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                            else
                                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: I now only work out the condition - `if (getTableView (). getSelectionModel (). getSelectedItems (). contains (auxPerson))`

Comment: What doesn't work, how does your table look like? And have you already tried to debug? With debugging you can check if the conditions are the problem or the methods which should change the style.

Comment: @MalteKölle What did I do? I added a `sout`, with this I watched what was in the cells, and the `item` records the data from the cells I need, but if I write `if (auxPerson.getTimeContract (). equals ("2019-04-09"))...` then it will not work. auxPerson shows me `ListProperty [value: []`, I don't understand why

Comment: @MalteKölle I want to make it so that if I find a specific date in the required column, then I need to repaint it

Comment: `getTimeContract` stores the value - `ObjectProperty [value: 2019-04-09]`, and I was sure that the `equals ("2019-04-09")` condition would work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This sounds like you are comparing an Object with a String which doesn't work. So try to get the Value of `ObjectProperty [value: 2019-04-09]`. Probably with `auxPerson.getTimeContract().getValue`. Anyways check @kleopatra comment and provide a minimal reproducible example. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using `LocalDate` for the column, it wouldn't be far fetched that you're using `LocalDate` for the other property too. If `getTimeContract` returns a property object, you're not adhering to the naming conventions and comparing a property object to a the contained object yields `false`. Even if you compare with the value stored in the property, it won't yield `true`, if this value is a `LocalDate`: The fact that 2 objects have the same string representation doesn't mean they're equal. E.g. the `String` object `"1"` is not equal to the `Integer` object `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Fabian was right, I did not take into account that I was comparing different objects, thanks for all the advice.

```
if (auxPerson.getTimeContract().toString().equals("2019-04-11"))
```